# print the rows of a matrix in two different sections in order to prevent the elements from mixing together

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath, matrices, multirow

As you see in the following picture I have a 4x4 matrix and the elements are so lengthy that they will not fit in a single line of an A4 paper.
In fact this equation is printed in a book that I'm translating. I'm not familiar with LateX and I'm just typing mathematical expression with LaTex in Mathtype. **So I can only use `amsmath` package and `math-mode` codes**
[image]

The question is how can I create the exact shape of equation in my LaTex code?
what I have done so far, is the following code:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
. & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & .
\end{bmatrix}
```

I know how to write each element of the matrix. In fact I know what to write instead of dots
I know for seperating elements of matrix in a single row, `&` should be used and to go to the next row, we should use `\\`
Also I'm familiar with `\cdots`, `ldots` and etc.
But I don't know how to rearrange the elements exactly like the picture and prevent them from mixing up together?

---

**Edit:**
LaRiFaRi's answer works well

```
\begin{align}
T_4 &= \langle \underline{k}\,.\,\underline{k}^{*^T} \rangle=
\left\langle 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\left|k_1\right|^2 & k_1k_2^* & k_1k_3^* & k_1k_4^*\\
k_2k_1^* & \left|k_2\right|^2 & k_2k_3^* & k_2k_4^*\\
k_3k_1^* & k_3k_2^* & \left|k_3\right|^2 & k_3k_4^*\\
k_4k_1^* & k_4k_2^* & k_4k_3^* & \left|k_4\right|^2
\end{bmatrix} 
\right\rangle
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{split}
\left[\begin{matrix}
\langle|S_{XX}+S_{YY}|^2\rangle & 
\langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &\\
\langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle & 
\langle|S_{XX}-S_{YY}|^2\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
\langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle& 
\langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
\langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle & 
\langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &
\end{matrix}\right.\\
\left.\begin{matrix}
& \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle 
& \langle -j(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
\cdots\cdots& \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle 
& \langle -j(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
\cdots\cdots& \langle|S_{XY}+S_{YX}|^2\rangle 
& \langle-j(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
& \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle 
& \langle|S_{XY}-S_{YX}|^2\rangle
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

It is displayed like this math.stackexchange.com
[image]

Comment: A minimal (non)working code would be nice to save us the tedium of typing the whole formulae. Could you post one so we can play with it?

Comment: It is a symmetric matrix. You don't need to type out every element. As you can see it takes quite some attention to see that it is a symmetric matrix which can be pretty obvious if you typeset it so. And what is the LR bracket operation, inner product?

Comment: @percusse LR bracket is for ensemble averaging

Comment: @Bernard I'll start now to try out LaRiFaRi's answer, then I will post the code here if I need more help and save you the tedium of typing the whole question

Comment: @percusse: it isn't really symmetric, as I can see it.

Comment: @Bernard Ah, I should have said Hermitian.

Comment: Even with hermitian: the elements in positions $(1,2)$  and $(2,1)$ are not exactly conjugates.

Comment: @Bernard Why not (AB*)* = (BA*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a 1 to 1 replica of this, it would look like:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ % or \begin{equation} if you want it numberd. 
\begin{split}
\left[\begin{matrix}
. & . &\\
. & . & \cdots\cdots\\
. & . & \cdots\cdots\\
. & . &
\end{matrix}\right.\\
\left.\begin{matrix}
& . & .\\
\cdots\cdots& . & .\\
\cdots\cdots& . & .\\
& . & .
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]